# Should a suppressed section in a Crystal Report have any impact on the report?

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I'm trying to use Crystal Reports with Microsoft Visual Studio.
Unfortunately I have many problems which aren't easily summarised.

I have a sub-report before my main Grouped section.
When this sub-report inexplicably fails to display the data it should, I'm also losing the page header sections on the report's first page. I don't know of any reason why the sub-report should effect/interact-with the page headers - I have no code or conditions for suppressing the page headers.

So, I tried suppressing the sub-report section - and I still lose my page headers. 
Finally, if I delete entirely the sub-report, I get my page headers back. 
It doesn't make sense to me. 
Any ideas as to what is going on?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What section is the sub-report in?

Comment: It is in its own page header section, below the page header section that mysteriously disappears. (Any help would be appreciated)

Comment: That may be the issue: sometimes the page header is before the group and sometimes after the group (or at least the group header).  Do you need to have it on every page?  It sounds like it would work better in the report header (or in its own report header section below the main one).